# Subclassing LinearLayout, how to determine gravity is LEFT or RIGHT

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am subclassing `LinearLayout`. In the subclass I can't figure out how to get the gravity value. I simply want to determine if the gravity set in xml layout is `Gravity.LEFT` or `Gravity.RIGHT`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: getchild(index) can help. if index is 1, its the left/top most item in the list

Comment: First try to get layout params of parent layout and get gravity value from layout params.

Comment: @Haresh can't get gravity from getLayoutParams(). Can you give an example. Thx

Comment: Have you cast getLayoutParams() to LinearLayout.getLayoutParams() after try to get gravity value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get gravity from parent layout params :

```
int gravity = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)((LinearLayout)childView.getParent()).getLayoutParams()).gravity;
if(gravity == Gravity.LEFT){
   // write your code when parent gravity is left           
}else if(gravity == Gravity.RIGHT){
   // write your code when parent gravity is right           
}else if(gravity == (Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)){
  // write your code when parent gravity is left with center vertical
else{
  // write your code when parent gravity is neither right nor left.
}
```

Comment: If gravity value in xml is something like this right|center_vertical then how to check?

Comment: @Sohaib,Very good question man i dont think about it but it is very interesting now!!!

Comment: I think proper way to check whether gravity is LEFT is something like this (gravity & Gravity.LEFT) == Gravity.LEFT

Comment: Accepting your answer. Thanks for all the help Haresh

Comment: No here no need check such kind of condition becz Gravity.LEFT return constant int value.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to check for gravity should be using the bitmask.

```
if ((gravity & Gravity.END) == Gravity.END) {
    // end/right justified
} 
if ((gravity & Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) == Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) {
    // center vertical
}
etc..
```